# Meaning of $d \theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, differential

I am confused with the notation $d \theta$.
Given a function $f: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$, is $\int _{|z|=r} f(z) d \theta= \int _0 ^{2\pi} f(re^{i \theta}) d \theta $ correct?

Also, can I use the ML inequality as follows?

If $|f(z)|<M$ then $|\int _{|z|=r} f(z) d \theta| \leq 2\pi rM$.

Comment: That $\mathrm d\theta$ doesn't make sense. It should be $\mathrm dz$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ahlfors's Complex Analysis uses lots of notations as in above, without explicit explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpretation
$$\int_{|z|=r}f(z)\>d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}f(re^{i\theta})\>d\theta$$
seems correct to me.

If $\bigl|f(z)\bigr|\leq M$ then one obtains
$$\left|\int_{|z|=r}f(z)\>d\theta\right|\leq 2\pi\,M\ ,$$
with no $r$ on the RHS, because the total measure of $d\theta$ is $2\pi$, independently of $r$.